# Unable to give print to pos 80 thermal printer from website; Locally it is working

Tags: thermal-printer

I have developed a PHP web POS application application.
Problem is related to invoice printing.

Current functionality:
1. I am using a Laser printer to print my invoice.
2. I am just calling JavaScript print() function, which open Crome browser's print dialog and give a print to my Laser Printer.
3. It is working fine.

New Functionality:
1. I have purchase a Themal Printer ( Pegasus PR8021 ).
2. I have attached printer with my laptop from USB.
3. I used Mike42 library to give a print to Themal Printer.
4. It is working fine, giveing a direct print to My Thermal print when I am running my code on my local machine.

Now Problem Comes:
1. I deployed my code to Blue Host hosting server (Linux server).
2. When I am running same code, then it is not able to find priner because connected to locallly.

3. Plese guide me step by step how i can configure my printet to print from any website.

I have researched alot, I have not found a proper step by step way how I can give a direct print to my Themral printer from a website
(Without openning Browsers print dialog).

Hope you understand the issue